# Pivot Table Refresh and Date Filter

Tags: vba, excel, pivot-table

I am having some difficulty with a report of mine, what I'd like to be able to do with VBA is to refresh all the pivot tables I have on my pivot table tab, but also add the new dates that will populate whenever I refresh my query.

To the Comment:
I do have a snippet of code I got here but it was just to update the tables (I need to combine that with grabbing the new dates that populate daily when the query is refreshed):

```html
Sub RefreshAllPivots()
   Dim PC As PivotCache
   For Each PC In ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
      PC.Refresh
   Next PC
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you made any VBA attempts at this yet?  If so, please post the code you have.

Comment: I do have a snippet of code, but I found it here, it simply refreshes the tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try recording a Macro of the action you want then review the code. Also, check out this link for someone who had a similar issue.

http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/392962-visual-basic-applications-manipulate-pivot-table-report-filter-2.html

Answer (score 0):

So you have to clear the filter for it to work right... IDK why that is, but whatever lol...

pt.PivotFields("SHIFTDT").ClearAllFilters

A section of my completed (tested and functioning) code:

```html
Sub RefreshAllPivots()

'= This will updated all the pivot tables in your workbook
    Dim PC As PivotCache
    For Each PC In ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches
       PC.Refresh
    Next PC
   
    Dim SttDT As Date
    Dim EndDT As Date
    Dim ThisDate As Date
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = Sheets("Pivot Tables").PivotTables("AWAYTIME")

'= This is just to setup the dates    
    Set ws = Worksheets("Pivot Tables")
    ThisDate = Date
    SttDT = "2/08/2015"
    EndDT = DateAdd("d", -1, ThisDate)
    ws.Select

'= This will perform  the actual action.  Replace your values under the
'= Set PT declaration, and change the SttDT and EndDT to your needs.
'= You can copy this section for as many tables you are updating.
    Set pt = Sheets("Pivot Tables").PivotTables("AWAYTIME")
    pt.PivotFields("SHIFTDT").ClearAllFilters
    pt.PivotFields("SHIFTDT").PivotFilters. _
    Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:=SttDT, Value2:=EndDT
    pt.PivotFields("SHIFTDT").AutoSort xlAscending, "SHIFTDT"

End Sub
```

Thank you for the reply, I have the answer.

```html
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("AWAYTIME").PivotFields("SHIFTDT").PivotFilters. _
    Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:="2/08/2015", Value2:=DateAdd("D", -1, Now())
```

So after the loop runs, I will just have to create one of these snippets for each table I am updating (like 12 or so) and it will set the range from the 8th of February through to whatever "yesterdays" date will be.

For anyone to modify if needed:

```html
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Your Pivot Table Name Here").PivotFields("Your Filter Field Here").PivotFilters. _
    Add Type:=xlDateBetween, Value1:="Your Start Date", Value2:"Your End Date"
```

Comment: Wow, well, it worked the first time I used it... now it won't this is damned odd...